# For an elliptic curve $X$, we have $X \cong \operatorname{Pic}^1(X)$. Why?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, line-bundles

In Lectures on Vector Bundles, Le Potier states that for an elliptic curve $X$ we have
$$ X \cong \operatorname{Pic}^1(X).$$
As far as I understand the map $x \mapsto [x]-[O]$ gives an isomorphism of $X$ and $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$, where $O$ is the point at infinity of the elliptic curve.

Why does the isomorphism above exist and why is it not a contradiction to $X \cong \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$?

Comment: The map $x \longmapsto [x]$ is an (obvious) isomorphism from $X$ to its $\mathrm{Pic}^1$ – simply because $D \longmapsto D-[O]$ is an obvious bijection from the set of degree-one Cartier divisors to the set of degree-zero Cartier divisors.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.